# x:FieldModifier causing problems within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

The code below puts a check edit inside the column header of the first column.  However, I need access to the check edit box (by name) in my C# code behind.  Can anyone tell me why I can't seem to use the `x:FieldModifier="public"` setting in the `CheckEdit` defined within the `DataTemplate`?  And yes, I do have the x:Class="...." defined in the root element of this file...it's just not shown below.

```
<Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl Name="gridControl_ExportList" AutoPopulateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        <dxg:GridControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="flagCustomizationArea">
                <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="checkEditSelectAllBox" x:FieldModifier="public" ToolTip="Select/Deselect All" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Checked="CheckEdit_SelectAllChecked" Unchecked="CheckEdit_SelectAllUnchecked"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dxg:GridControl.Resources>

        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Name="isSelected" x:FieldModifier="public" Header="" Width="27" AllowResizing="False" FieldName="IsSelected" HeaderCustomizationAreaTemplate="{StaticResource flagCustomizationArea}"/>
```

I realize some of the code here is DevExpress related, but the issue at hand seems to be a problem with XAML in general.  Thanks in advance for any insight you can give.  BTW, the exact error I'm getting is "The attribute 'FieldModifier' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'.

EDIT:  Yes, it makes sense what you say.  Thanks for your answer.  How, then, would I go about unchecking that column header check box in C# code-behind?  Currently, when the user clicks that column header check box, it selects all the check boxes in that column.  When the user un-checks that column header check box it unselects all the check boxes in that column.  This is the behavior I want.  However, after some operation when the table is updated, I want the column header to be unchecked.  The checkboxes on all the rows will update as they should since they are bound to data.  After operation X for example, some checkboxes maybe checked, others not; therefore I don't want the header check box checked anymore.  How do I get the column header checkbox to un-check?  My initial thinking was if I made it public, I could just set it to unchecked.  However, your explanation makes sense and I can't do this.

Comment: You cannot use this modifier inside a template. Think about it: if you are going to have more than one control using this template, each template generating its own checkbox, which checkbox is your field going to refer to? Describe the problem you are trying to solve with the modifier. Probably there is a different way to go about it.

Comment: Please see my "EDIT" in the original question.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'd make the column check state (it's really 3-state as you describe it by the way) bound to the piece of your viewmodel corresponding to the column. Establish a two-way binding (then you can handle your custom logic in the property setter), or bind the check/uncheck action to a command on the same viewmodel and have this logic in the command handler. On modification of the rows' selection states set the column state property to 'indeterminate' (null). WPF philosophy works best with data binding. Event handlers and user control code-behind are best saved for custom UI look-and-feel stuff.